# Unable to install GNOME extensions on Ubuntu Budgie

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell-extension, ubuntu-budgie

I have installed Ubuntu Budgie 20.04. I am new to Ubuntu environment. I want to install and try new GNOME extensions. So, I searched the Internet and found that I have to install GNOME Tweak Tool. So I installed it through

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then I installed Chrome browser extension GNOME Shell integration and native host connector by running

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

Even though, I have installed every necessary repositories I am still unable to install extension. I am getting an error on GNOME Shell extension website as shown in the following image.

> Unable to locate GNOME Shell settings or version. Make sure it is installed and running.
>   [image: Unable to locate GNOME Shell settings or version. Make sure it is installed and running.]

I have tried every possible solution that is available on Internet but no luck.
Note : Extension application is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNOME Extensions are designed for only one desktop environment called GNOME Shell.

Budgie Desktop is its own unique interface and does not support GNOME Extensions.

The equivalent in Ubuntu Budgie are "Budgie Applets" - there are lots to choose from - Menu - Budgie Applets.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. First, install this : sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
2. dont use firefox from budgie app store, download firefox from [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)

3. Extract and run firefox and then close it
4. Open budgie app store, uninstall firefox from there. This is important!!! don't try to purge / uninstall from terminal. After succesful uninstall, restart.
5. Open firefox (the one that you extract) and install gnome extension
6. Refresh the gnome extension page. Now you can install gnome extension.
7. After install extension, open your budgie menu, and search for extension, you can setting, enable, disable or remove extension from there.

No need to install gnome tweaks

Goodluck