# Broken and Ugly App Switcher Ubuntu Budgie 20.04

Tags: 20.04, application-switcher, budgie, ubuntu-budgie

I was quite happy with using my installation of Ubuntu Budgie but recently something broke and now my app switcher looks very ugly. It's working but I liked how it used to look. I guess re-installing some package would fix this but I'm not sure which one it is. Anyone faced something similar and can help?

This is how it looks like:
[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with budgie, but it seems to me that you need to install some other budgie applet for app switching. Look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235248/unable-to-install-gnome-extensions-on-ubuntu-budgie

Comment: Yes there's one app switcher applet which I've reinstalled but that didn't help. :(
I'm also fine if I can install any external app switcher to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of app-switcher with Ubuntu Budgie

The first is the standard alt+tab switcher.

[image]

The second is the previews switcher.  In your picture you have the previews switcher enabled.

You can disable this via Menu - Previews Control.  Logout and login and the default app-switcher will reappear.